# Python. Selenium misses element

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, xpath

I need to get feedbacks from [site](https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/New-Original-Xiaomi-Mi-Band-2-Miband-Wistband-Bracelet-with-Smart-Heart-Rate-Fitness-Touchpad-OLED/32677212146.html?spm=2114.01010208.3.1.nXc9Wn&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0%2Csearchweb201602_0_10065_10068_10084_10083_10080_10082_10081_10110_10136_10111_10137_10060_10112_10138_10113_10062_10114_10141_10056_10055_10037_128_10054_10059_10099_10078_10079_10077_10103_10073_10102_10096_10070_10122_10123_10144_10052_10053_10124_10142_10107_10050_10143_10051%2Csearchweb201603_0%2Cafswitch_1%2CppcSwitch_5%2Csingle_sort_0_default&btsid=bb96f999-5b48-47c4-8605-d04f86ebeaf6&algo_expid=b8d752f3-57dc-43e0-8d73-4b008ae3600a-0&algo_pvid=b8d752f3-57dc-43e0-8d73-4b008ae3600a)

Feedbacks are inside `<iframe>` tag, so I go to `iframe`, and i get feedbacks, from the first page, but then i need change page using button:

[image]

Selenium can find it by class or xpath, but when it tries to click it returns error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="100%" height="1943" src="//feedback.aliexpress.com/display/productEvaluation.htm?productId=1000003578539&amp;ownerMemberId=825321852&amp;companyId=&amp;memberType=seller&amp;startValidDate=" cd_frame_id_="9dbc34cc8793cee8fbcab5180296b0d6"></iframe> is not clickable at point (1001, 582). Other element would receive the click: <span data-role="show" class="show-history">...</span>
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Here is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

close_popup = driver.find_element_by_class_name('close-layer')
close_popup.click()

tab_feedback = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="j-product-tabbed-pane"]/ul/li[2]')
tab_feedback.click()

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[starts-with(@src, "//feedback.aliexpress.com/display/productEvaluation.htm")]'))

text_feedbacks = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('buyer-feedback')

next = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ui-pagination-next ui-goto-page')
next.click()
```

I thought that maybe selenium too fast, I tried to wait and loop but still can't get next page of feedbacks. Also i tried to get this element using xpath:

```
next = driver.find_element_by_xpath( "//div[@class='ui-pagination-navi util-left']/a[@class='ui-goto-page']")
```

But nothing helps.

How can i get next page of feedbacks using selenium? Why other element receives click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[starts-with(@src, "//feedback.aliexpress.com/display/productEvaluation.htm")]'))

text_feedbacks = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('buyer-feedback')
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
next = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Next")
next.click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

The problem is that `span` `"Recently viewed"` element overlaps required button and so intercepts the click... You might need just to scroll page a little (in provided code- by simulating `Page Down` button pressing)

Note that you should switch back from `iframe` after clicking `"Next"` button

Comment: It finds element, but when click returns    same error   </iframe> is not clickable at point (1009, 590). Other element would receive the click: <span data-role="show" class="show-history">...</span>

Comment: Yeap, I got it now... Added little hack ;) Try updated.

Comment: It is working, thanks! What was the reason of problem?Why other element received click?

Comment: I've added clarification to answer. This is because of `"Recently viewed"` tab in right bottom corner of page which covers required button

Answer (score 0):

You need to set delay for each `tab_feedback.click()` because the page has not been loaded fully.

```
import time
time.sleep(5)
```